How do i pass an Image to a Roxie Query?
The image is basically to test CNN based classification model on HPCC Cluster.
Is it possible to pass a string representing the image, or even the model outputs ; was a topic of discussion.
The model outputs here refer to predicted class labels and probabilities.

I think the best approach to this would be to load your images into a BLOB dataset that is described in the Programmer's Guide here: Working with BLOBs. From there, you can pass any record in your image dataset to the query and then process the DATA string from there. The ROXIE query could build a standard index into that dataset and then FETCH the image string as needed.
Essentially you are correct that the core to this is converting the image files into a string, and this BLOB processing make it easier.
I am also trying to locate some research that was done with GNN and image preprocessing. I will post back when I find it.
Here is a link to that project repo that is working on image preprocessing with GNN:
HPCC_GNN_P02
Bob

I wanted to also know what is the maximum memory size of a string that can be passed to a roxie query?

The upper size limit for any STRING value is 4GB.
